# Get user from table based on id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these Postgres tables:

```
create table deals_new
(
    id                  bigserial primary key,
    slip_id             text,
    deal_type           integer,
    timestamp           timestamp,
    employee_id         bigint
        constraint employee_id_fk
            references common.employees
);

create table twap
(
    id                 bigserial     primary key,
    deal_id            varchar          not null,
    employee_id        bigint
        constraint fk_twap__employee_id
            references common.employees,
    status             integer
);

create table employees
(
    id              bigint primary key,
    account_id      integer,     
    first_name      varchar(150),
    last_name       varchar(150)
);


New table to query:

create table accounts
(
    id               bigint primary key,
    account_name     varchar(150) not null
);
```

I use this SQL query:

```
select d.*, t.id as twap_id 
from common.deals_new d 
    left outer join common.twap t on 
        t.deal_id = d.slip_id and
        d.timestamp between '11-11-2021' AND '11-11-2021' and
        d.deal_type in (1, 2) and
        d.quote_id is null
where d.employee_id is not null
order by d.timestamp desc, d.id
offset 10
limit 10;
```

How I can extend this SQL query to search also in table `employees` by `account_id` and map the result in table `accounts` by `id`? I would like to print also `accounts. account_name` based on `employees .account_id`.

Comment: [Edit] the question and complete the [example] by also providing `INSERT` statements for sample data (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two joins to to make this work for you. One join to get to the employee table, and one more join to get to the accounts table.

```
select d.*, t.id as twap_id, a.account_name
from common.deals_new d 
    left outer join common.twap t on 
        t.deal_id = d.slip_id and
        d.timestamp between '11-11-2021' AND '11-11-2021' and
        d.deal_type in (1, 2) and
        d.quote_id is null
    join employees as e on d.employee_id = e.id
    join accounts as a on a.id = e.account_id 
where d.employee_id is not null
order by d.timestamp desc, d.id
offset 10
limit 10;
```

Note: I did not fiddle this one, so could have a typo, but I think you get the idea here.