# Add join to display items based on key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these Postgres tables:

```
create table employees
(
    id              bigint primary key,
    account_id      number,
    first_name      varchar(150),
    last_name       varchar(150)
);

create table accounts
(
    id               bigint primary key,
    account_name     varchar(150) not null
);
```

I need to search in table `employees` by account_id and print result the rows which match in table `accounts`.`id`. How I can do this using JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT a.id, a.account_name, e.first_name, e.last_name
FROM employees as e
    JOIN accounts as a on a.id = e.account_id
WHERE e.account_id = 3
```

This will allow you to search for specific account IDs in the employee table and bring back their corresponding account table information.

You can check this with my dbfiddle here - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pwzwQTsHuP27UDF17eAQy4/0

Comment: Thanks! One additional question: Where I have to place this JOIN in this query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70679861/get-user-from-table-based-on-id

Comment: I believe I answered you next question as well.